# Create Hash iterating an array of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an object that has attributes `name` and `data`, among others. I want to create a hash that uses the name as the key and the data (which is an array) as the value. I can't figure out how to reduce the code below using `map`. Is it possible?

```
def fc_hash
  fcs = Hash.new
  self.forecasts.each do |fc|
    fcs[fc.name] = fc.data
  end
  fcs
end
```

Comment: `map` returns an array, and will not return a hash. But that said, there isn't really anything wrong with this code. Why not use it just like you have it?

Comment: Hash[*self.forecasts.map{ [fc.name, fc.data]}.flatten]

Comment: What is `forecasts`? Particularly, what is its class?

Comment: @sawa It seems reasonable to assume it's an array of `Forecast` instances, doesn't it?

Comment: In Ruby, `{ }` is almost always preferable to `Hash.new`. The only reason to call the formal constructor is for passing in defaults, like `Hash.new(0)` or `Hash.new { |h,k| ... }`.

Comment: @AlexWayne the structure of create an empty object and then filling it with a block is redundant in case of Array, because of the `map` method. I thought there was some alternative for the Hash case; great to know the original code seems ok! :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use [`Hash[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D):

```
Forecast = Struct.new(:name, :data)
forecasts = [Forecast.new('bob', 1), Forecast.new('mary', 2)]
Hash[forecasts.map{|forecast| [forecast.name, forecast.data]}]
# => {"mary"=>2, "bob"=>1}
```

Answer (score 14):

```
def fc_hash
 forecasts.each_with_object({}) do |forecast, hash|
    hash[forecast.name] = forecast.data
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, you both do seem very enamored of it :p

Answer (score 3):

I always use `inject` or `reduce` for this:

```
self.forecasts.reduce({}) do |h,e|
  h.merge(e.name => e.data)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Hash[*self.forecases.map{ [fc.name, fc.data]}.flatten]
```

Comment: Job security: 1, Readability: 0.

Comment: if the reader understands what map and flatten is this is pretty easy to read

Comment: You need to understand not only what `Hash[]` is but also what `*` does in that context. It's clever and concise, but a bit too intense for one line.

Comment: But you don't need the splat or the `flatten`, they're just noise as `Hash[]` is quite happy with an array-of-arrays. You're also missing something in the `map` block.

Answer (score 0):

With Ruby 2.1 and onward, you could also use `Array#to_h`

```
self.forecasts.to_h { |forecast| [forecast.name, forecast.data] }
```